# How to print the content from a text file with one blank line after each line?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

This is what I type and the output I get:

```
$ cat helloworld.txt

Hello World!
I'm Kanladaporn Sirithatthamrong
6480952
```

But this is what I want an output to be:

```
Hello World!

I'm Kanladaporn Sirithatthamrong

6480952
```

What should I do?
Any suggestions please?

Comment: Your example does not show a blank line after each line. I assume that is what you want.

Comment: Your title does not match the question. Do you want to insert a blank line after each line in text file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `pr`:

```
$ pr -Td helloworld.txt
Hello World!

I'm Kanladaporn Sirithatthamrong

6480952

$
```

From [`man pr`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/pr.1.html):

```
   -d, --double-space
          double space the output

   -T, --omit-pagination
              omit page headers and trailers, eliminate any pagination by form feeds set in input files
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed G helloworld.txt
```

To only add newlines when there isn't already a blank line, use:

```
sed '/^$/d;G' helloworld.txt
```

Reference: [Handy one-liners for SED](https://edoras.sdsu.edu/doc/sed-oneliners.html)

Answer (score 1):

Change the output record separator of awk to two newlines instead of the default one:

```
awk 'BEGIN { ORS = "\n\n"} { print }' helloworld.txt
```

Comment: You could also shorten this to `awk -v ORS='\n\n' '1' helloworld.txt`

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print;print ""}' helloworld.txt
```